# tar error to a Drobo FS: Cannot close: Input/output error, Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Tags: tar, drobo

We've been running this tar backup from a Fedora 25 workstation to a Drobo FS for a couple of years and in the past few weeks it's starting to error out with the following but does seem to complete:

```
/bin/tar: /mypath/etc-new.tgz: Cannot close:
Input/output error
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

STANDARD OUTPUT:
Failed to rename /mypath/home-new.tgz to
/mypath/home.tgz: File exists

Backup of /etc FAILED

Backed up /etc to /mypath/etc-FAILED.tgz
Backed up /root to /mypath/root.tgz
Backed up /usr/local to /mypath/usr-local.tgz
Backed up /var/lib to /mypath/var-lib.tgz
Backed up /var/log to /mypath/var-log.tgz
Backed up /var/www to /mypath/var-www.tgz
Backed up /var/yp to /mypath/var-yp.tgz
Second try renamed /mypath/home-new.tgz to
/mypath/home.tgz
```

Here's the full tar command in action:

```
/usr/local/sbin/drobo-backup -n -v -c /etc/drobo-backup.conf
\Reading configfile /etc/drobo-backup.conf
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/home-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed home --exclude=.gvfs --exclude='Windows 7.vdi'
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/etc-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed etc
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/root-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed root
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/usr-local-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed usr/local
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/var-lib-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed var/lib --exclude=/var/lib/yum --exclude=/var/lib/rpm
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/var-log-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed var/log
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/var-www-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed var/www
/bin/mkdir /mypath
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n19 /bin/tar -cf /mypath/var-yp-new.tgz -C / --atime-preserve --one-file-system --warning=no-file-ignored --warning=no-file-changed --warning=no-file-removed var/yp
```

The only logs that I can see that might be related are these which are about 30 minutes before the error report arrives by email:

```
Mar  3 01:08:31 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: Server drobo has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
Mar  3 01:09:29 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: sends on sock ffff99407356fc00 stuck for 15 seconds
Mar  3 01:09:29 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: Error -11 sending data on socket to server
Mar  3 01:09:44 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: sends on sock ffff99407356fc00 stuck for 15 seconds
Mar  3 01:09:44 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: Error -11 sending data on socket to server
Mar  3 01:10:25 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: sends on sock ffff99407356fc00 stuck for 15 seconds
Mar  3 01:10:25 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: Error -11 sending data on socket to server
Mar  3 01:12:09 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: sends on sock ffff994089f78a00 stuck for 15 seconds
Mar  3 01:12:09 myworkstation kernel: CIFS VFS: Error -11 sending data on socket to server
```

A maintainer of GNU tar [says this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-tar/2017-02/msg00010.html):

> The 'close()' syscall returned non-zero value and errno was set to EIO.
>   That sounds like some underlying issue with your hardware.

But the self tests on the Drobo FS do not indicate any errors or warnings. The `tar`s do complete but perhaps there's something with the command or "[position-sensitive](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Position_002dSensitive-Options.html)" syntax? The error always happens on `/etc/`. We have a few other workstations doing these exact same backups to the same Drobo FS and no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem. It seems [Tracker](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) was the culprit. Here are some clues from logs:

```
ouruser journal: *** Unsupported operation detected on trash directory
ouruser journal:  dir: /home/users/username/.local/share/Trash/files, file: files, type: 4#012
ouruser journal: unable to create file '/run/user/1234/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
ouruser journal: kde-recent-document-provider.vala:174: Couldn't find actor for 'kpdf'.
ouruser journal: Could not create FTS delete statement: table fts5 has no column named nco:hobby
ouruser journal: unable to create file '/run/user/1234/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
ouruser journal: Could not create FTS delete statement: table fts5 has no column named nco:hobby
ouruser kernel: CIFS VFS: Server drobo-rh has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
ouruser kernel: CIFS VFS: sends on sock ffff8d96e7af4000 stuck for 15 seconds
ouruser kernel: CIFS VFS: Error -11 sending data on socket to server
```

And from the cron job running the tar backup:

```
ERROR OUTPUT:
/bin/tar: /ourdomain/etc-new.tgz: Cannot close:
Input/output error
/bin/tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

STANDARD OUTPUT:
Failed to rename /drobo/ourdomain/home-new.tgz to
/ourdomain/home.tgz: File exists

Backup of /etc FAILED
```

So `/home` is on its own partition:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_ouruser-LogVol02 /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
```

I believe Tracker ends up running during the backup, and was trying to index the Trash. When the backup finishes `/home` and continues to `/etc` that's when the tar errors appear. I deleted the Trash of this user and then decided to [remove the Tracker RPM](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/82306/removeuninstall-tracker/). The error has disappeared (hopefully permanently!).